# GPIO not going high and code being ignored when running PI4J

Tags: java, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to control a GPIO pin in my program to turn on a simple relay all of the code works apart from one issue; the GPIO pin code to send the signal high isn't working, and isn't causing any errors either, i am using the pi4j libraries to control the pins on the RaspberryPi Board.

Here is my code:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;


import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class FileWatch {

    static String clkID;
    static String clkID2;
    static String ts;
    static String ts1;
    static boolean done = false;
    static boolean REdone = false;
    static boolean finished = false;
    static boolean ready;

    static String host ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dancers";
    static String username ="root";
    static String password ="beaker19";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

       // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        // provision gpio pin #01 as an output pin and turn on
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, "MyLED", PinState.LOW);


        while (true) {
            done = false;
            REdone=false;
            checkFile();
            System.out.println("worked");
            pin.high();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            REcheckFile();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            //Thread.
            if (clkID.equals(clkID2)) {

            uploadTimes();

            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Wrong matching ID's");
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pin.low();
         }
    }   

    // Thread th = new Thread(new FileWatch());
    // th.start();
    // checkFile();
    // REcheckFile();
    // if (clkID2.equals(clkID2)){
    // System.out.println("worked");
    // }
    // else {
    // System.out.println("not worked");
    // }
    //
    public static void check() throws InterruptedException{

        checkFile();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        REcheckFile();
        Thread.sleep(500);

    }


    public String getClkId() {

        return clkID;

    }

    public static void connection() {

//      while(!finished){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("worked");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      }
    }


    public static void checkFile() {
        while (!done) {
            try {
                WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                        .newWatchService();
                Path dir = Paths.get("/home/pi/rpi2ardu");
                dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY);

                System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: "
                        + dir.getFileName());

                WatchKey key;
                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    Path fileName = ev.context();

                    System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);

                    if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY
                            && fileName.toString().equals("example.txt")) {
                        System.out.println("My source file has changed!!!");
                        String sCurrentLine = null;
                        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/example.txt"))) {
                            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                                clkID = sCurrentLine;
                                System.out.println(clkID);
                                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                                date = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
                                // System.out.println(new
                                // Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                                ts = date.toString();
                                System.out.println(ts);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        File inputFile = new File("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/example.txt"); // Your
                                                                            // file
                        File tempFile = new File("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/temp.txt");// temp
                                                                                // file
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader(inputFile));
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new FileWriter(tempFile));
                        String currentLine;
                        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            currentLine = ("");
                            writer.write(currentLine);
                        }
                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                        done = true;
                        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
                        System.out.println(successful);
                    }
                }

                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void REcheckFile() {
        while (!REdone) {
            try {
                WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                        .newWatchService();
                Path dir = Paths.get("/home/pi/rpi2ardu");
                dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_MODIFY);

                System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: "
                        + dir.getFileName());

                WatchKey key;
                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    Path fileName = ev.context();

                    System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);

                    if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY
                            && fileName.toString().equals("example.txt")) {
                        System.out.println("My source file has changed!!!");
                        String sCurrentLine = null;
                        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/example.txt"))) {
                            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                                clkID2 = sCurrentLine;
                                System.out.println(clkID2);
                                java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
                                date1 = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
                                // System.out.println(new
                                // Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                                String ts1 = date1.toString();
                                System.out.println(ts1);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        File inputFile = new File("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/example.txt"); // Your
                                                                            // file
                        File tempFile = new File("/home/pi/rpi2ardu/temp.txt");// temp
                                                                                // file
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader(inputFile));
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new FileWriter(tempFile));
                        String currentLine;
                        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            currentLine = ("");
                            writer.write(currentLine);
                        }
                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                        REdone = true;
                        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
                        System.out.println(successful);
                    }
                }

                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void uploadTimes(){
          try
            {
              String host ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dancers";
                String username ="root";
                String password ="beaker19";
                connection();
               Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
                System.out.println("Connected:");

                String t1= ts;
                String t2 =ts1;
                String id =clkID;

                // the mysql insert statement
                String query = " insert into test (id, ts, ts1)"
                  + " values (?, ?, ?)";     
              // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
              java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
              preparedStmt.setString (1, id);
              preparedStmt.setString (2, t1);
              preparedStmt.setString (3, t2);

              // execute the preparedstatement
              preparedStmt.execute();
              System.out.println("worked"); 
              conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              System.err.println("Got an exception!");
              System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }


}
```

Im not sure why it isnt sending the gpio signal high and i am not seeing any results its just ommits the code like it wasnt there.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Are you positive that you're using the correct resistors? If not, it is possible that a signal is going through but it is not strong enough to be detected on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Make sure you are using the correct GPIO pin number. The pin numbering of Pi4J is different than the usual two ways of numbering in python. Take a look at this link: http://pi4j.com/pins/model-2b-rev1.html
2. Relays usually require high current to switch. The current provided by a GPIO pin is not enough to trigger most relays. Hook up an LED and resistor to that GPIO pin to test whether the problem is the pin not turning high or whether it is the relay requiring more current than the pin can supply.